React project with Pdfjs-dist to convert pdf to images . display it in webpage. without download pdf direct
im working on React project using pdfjs-dist.
im convert pdf into images to show on a webpage.
when im in development mode.
pdfjs-dist work good.
but when im in live mode.
this message appear.
"The API version "3.11.174" does not match the Worker version "4.8.69"."
how can i solve it.
this is code.
import * as pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist";
import "/public/pdf.worker.min.mjs";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useGetPdfCanva(pdfUrl) {
const [pages, setPages] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);



 useEffect(() => {
  const loadPdf = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(
      `${base}Dropbox/FetchPdf?sharedLink=${pdfUrl}`,
    );
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Failed to fetch PDF");

    const blob = await response.blob();
    const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(objectUrl).promise;

    const renderPage = async (i) => {
      const page = await pdf.getPage(i);
      const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1 });
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas.height = viewport.height;
      canvas.width = viewport.width;
      await page.render({ canvasContext: context, viewport }).promise;
      return canvas.toDataURL();
    };

    const pagesArray = await Promise.all(
      Array.from({ length: pdf.numPages }, (_, i) => renderPage(i + 1)),
    );

    setLoading(false);
    setPages(pagesArray);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error loading PDF:", error);
       }
     };
     loadPdf();
     }, [pdfUrl]);

      return { pages, loading };
   }

